# Identifying stopping times

Tags: measure-theory, finance, stopping-times

Possibly should have posted this to the Stats board, but the question is to identify which of the following are stopping times;

\begin{align}
\tau_1 &= \mathbb{inf } \{ t \in \mathbb{N}_0 ; Y_t = 10 \} \\
\tau_2 &= \mathbb{inf } \{ t \in \mathbb{N}_0 ; Y_t \in \{2,5,7\} \}\\
\tau_3 &= \mathbb{inf } \{ t \in \mathbb{N}_0 ; Y_{t+1} \in \{2,5,7\} \}\\
\tau_4 &= \mathbb{sup } \{ t \leq\mathbb{N}_0 ; Y_t = 3\}\\
\end{align}

This is in a probability space $(\Omega, \mathbb{P})$ with $(Y_t)^\infty_{t=0}$ as a sequence of iid random variables. The space is endowed with the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)^T_{t=0}$ with $\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma(Y_0,...,Y_t)$.

I think, though my understanding is very small, that perhaps $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are, whereas $\tau_3$ and $\tau_4$ aren't. Could anyone shed some light as to whether these are correct?

My solutions would be:

$\tau_1$ is a stopping time since $\{\tau_1=t\} = \{Y_0 = ... = Y_{t-1} = 0, Y_t = 10\} = \left(\bigcap^{t-1}_{s=1}\{Y_s = 0\} \right) \cap \{Y_t = 10\}$ and both $\{Y_s = 0\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$ for $s \leq t$ and $\{Y_t = 10\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$.

$\tau_2$. For this I've been thinking if we are stopping the first time $Y_t \in \{2,5,7\}$, then surely we are just looking for the first time $Y_t \gt 2$, in which case the argument is similar to above?

$\tau_3$ is not a stopping time since $Y_{t+1} \not\in \mathcal{F}_t$.

$\tau_4$ is not a stopping time since $t$ only runs to $10$, we may not see $Y_t = 3$.

Many thanks for any help! The more I think about each one the less I am sure about the answers...

Comment: 1) It is correct that $\tau_1$ is a stopping time, but your reasoning is not. Why do you think that $\tau_1(\omega)=t$ implies $Y_0(\omega)=\ldots=Y_{t-1}(\omega)=0$....? 2) Yes, $\tau_2$ is a stopping time and the reasoning is indeed similiar to the reasoning for $\tau_1$. 3) In general, $\tau_3$ and $\tau_4$ fail to be stopping times, but for instance if the random variables $Y_t$ are trivial, then they **are** stopping times.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am not sure why, sadly this was a similar exercise to a worked example I had and this was the method used. Having looked again the example answered with this argument. Why is this wrong?

Comment: Well, for instance if $\mathbb{P}(Y_k = 10) = \mathbb{P}(Y_k = -10)$, then $Y_k$ doesn't take the value $0$ at all and therefore $Y_k(\omega)=0$ does not hold for any $\omega$ and $k$. In particular, $\{\tau_1 = t\} = \{Y_0=\ldots = Y_{t-1} = 0, Y_t=10\}$ does **not** hold true.

Comment: My apologies, I've just read the question again and we are to assume that $\mathbb{P}\left[Y_t = n\right] \gt 0$ for all $t,n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ so I assume that clears it up?

Comment: No, there is still no reason why the process should be $0$ before hitting $10$.

Comment: Oh god, I see now. My apologies, I'm a bit stupid clearly. So how about if we change the equality to $Y_s \lt 10$ for all $s \leq t$.

Comment: Well, that's better, but still not correct... it could happen that $Y_s>10$ for $s <\tau_1$. Let's agree that $$\{\tau_1 = t\} = \{Y_1 \neq 10, \ldots, Y_{t-1} \neq 10, Y_t = 10\}, $$ right?

Comment: Well that's a definite! Thank you very much for your help, it was much appreciated and has cleared up much more than you may think!